# варианты сортировки

Tags: sql, postgresql

есть 2 таблицы:

table_a:

| id | name |

table_b:

| id | table_a_id | name | order |

в итоге хочу отсортировать по table_b.order. Если B1 -> то получить A3, A2, A1

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b1860/2

```
with t_b as (
    select name, table_a_id, "order" 
    from table_b
    where name = 'B1'
)

select a.name, b.name, b."order" 
from t_b b
join table_a a on a.id = b.table_a_id
order by b."order" desc;
```

как можно избавиться от with?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b1860/8

```
select a.name, b.name, b."order"
from table_a a
join table_b b 
   on b.table_a_id = a.id
order by
   case 
   when b.name = 'B1' 
   then b."order" 
   else -1 
   end desc, a.id asc
```

но тут получаются дубли записей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понят требуемое, то

```
select a.name, b.name, b."order"
from table_a a
join table_b b 
  on b.table_a_id = a.id and b.name = 'B1'
order by b."order" desc;
```